# python - Json data with different keys

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I am trying to store two run options in Json. My attempt is as below. Is this a sensible way to organise Json object? Also how can I read either of them into tuples? I tried `tuple([(item['opt_one'],item['val_one']) for item in config['opts']])` but git a key error. Many thanks for your help.

```
"opts":[
    {
        "opt_one": "one_option",
        "val_one" : "value_one"
     },
     {
        "opt_two": "two_option",
        "val_two" : "value_two"
      }
      ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# or it can be done in 1 line
print(tuple(map(lambda v: tuple(v.values()), J['opts'])))
```

Comment: thanks a lot. But how can I also read either one of them, for example only opt_two and val_two into a tuple?

Comment: opts is a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary has an index (starting at 0). Each dictionary has keys() or values() or both - items(). J['opts'][0] and J['opts'][1] are the 2 dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

j = """
{"opts":[
    {
        "opt_one": "one_option",
        "val_one" : "value_one"
     },
     {
        "opt_two": "two_option",
        "val_two" : "value_two"
      }
    ]
}
"""
# note the braces around "opts"

J = json.loads(j) #turns it into a python object
print(J) #see!

# the long way to do it, but you can see the process
R = []
for item in J['opts']:
    r = []
    for v in item.values():
        r.append(v)
    R.append(tuple(r))

print(tuple(R)) # solution
```